# How create bug work item in visual studio online from wpf app or some other web app?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a bugs list managed in a WPF app. I would like to create the bug in the VSO work item. Is there an API available to create work items like bug or task in Visual Studio Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there has the REST API to [create a work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item). The example code as:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

public void CreateBug()
{
   string _personalAccessToken = "your personal access token";
   string _credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", _personalAccessToken)));

   Object[] patchDocument = new Object[4];

   patchDocument[0] = new { op = "add", path = "/fields/System.Title", value = "Authorization Errors" };
   patchDocument[1] = new { op = "add", path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps", value = "Our authorization logic needs to allow for users with Microsoft accounts (formerly Live Ids) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826547.aspx" };
   patchDocument[2] = new { op = "add", path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority", value = "1" };
   patchDocument[3] = new { op = "add", path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity", value = "2 - High" };

   //use the httpclient
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
       //set our headers
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", _credentials);

       //serialize the fields array into a json string
       var patchValue = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDocument), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json"); 

       var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
       var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, "https://accountname.visualstudio.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workitems/$Bug?api-version=2.2") { Content = patchValue };
       var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

       //if the response is successfull, set the result to the workitem object
       if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
           var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
       }
   }
}
```

More details, you can refer [create bug](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/samples#create-bug).